# Getting Subclipse in Aptana to work with the newest release of Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana, subclipse

The version of **Subclipse (1.2.4)** currently available through Aptana's automatic *Plugins Manager* does not work with the newest version of Subversion.

I see on the Subclipse website however that they have 1.4.2 out for Eclipse. So I added a [new remote update site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.4.x) to my Update manager. When I tried to install it, it told me I needed **Mylyn 3.0.0**. So after much searching I found Mylyn 3.0.0 and added [another new remote update site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.3) to my update manager. Then when I tried to install that, it told me I needed **org.eclipse.ui 3.3.0** or equivalent.

Looking at the configuration details for Aptana, it looks like it is built against eclipse 3.2.2.

Does anyone know if there is a way to upgrade the version of Eclipse Aptana that is built against to 3.3.0? Or if there is some other way to get Subclipse to work with the very newest version of Subversion?

I know this isn't necessarily a "programming" question, but I hope it's ok since it's highly relevant to the programming experience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Subclipse does not require Mylyn, but the update site includes a plugin that integrates Mylyn and Subclipse.  This is intended for people that use Mylyn.  In your case, you would want to just de-select Mylyn in the update dialog.

Subclipse also requires Subversion 1.5 and the corresponding version of the JavaHL native libraries.  I have written the start of an FAQ to help people understand JavaHL and how to get it.  See: http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/wiki/JavaHL

Answer (score 7):

I've had problems with JavaHL in Eclipse Ganymede, when it worked fine in Eclipse Europa.  I'm not sure how Aptana is different, but try either upgrading JavaHL or switching to the pure-java SVNKit implementation within the Subclipse config.

Answer (score 4):

if you're not going to be using mylyn just uncheck that dependency. I'm not really familiar with Aptana, but in eclipse you can expand whats being installed and uncheck anything you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

I used the update url and I installed the JavaHL adapter, the Subclipse project itself **and** the SVNKit adapter BETA.

After this it worked fine for me, this is for linux platform hope it works for you.